# Is there a better way to sum an element to a list of different length?

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, addition

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe with itertools or operator, or something else?

I'm currently doing this way.

```
main_tx = [100, 200]
add_tx = [1, 2, 3]

tx = []
for x in main_tx:
    for user_x in add_tx:
        t = x + user_x
        tx.append(t)
print(tx) #[101, 102, 103, 201, 202, 203]
```

Comment: where did the 104 and 204 came from?

Comment: @ronpi sorry I had a typo and I've edited it to make the changes. Expected output should be [101, 102, 103, 201, 202, 203]

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension:

```
>>> [x + y for x in main_tx for y in add_tx]
[101, 102, 103, 104, 201, 202, 203, 204]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely can use `itertools` with its `product` function which iterates the cartesian product of given iterables (two `list` objects in your case):

```py
from itertools import product

main_tx = [100, 200]
add_tx = [1, 2, 3]

tx = []
for x, user_x in product(main_tx, add_tx):
    tx.append(x + user_x)
```

Now, you can do it more efficient and more pythonic using list comprehension:

```py
tx = [x + user_x for x, user_x in product(main_tx, add_tx)]
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments by [@don't talk just code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69218818/is-there-a-better-way-to-sum-an-element-to-a-list-of-different-length/69218921#comment122342115_69218921), you can also do this:

```py
tx = list(map(sum, product(main_tx, add_tx)))
```

Which would probably be the most efficient way to achieve the result

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that's quite useful. So If I have a ty list, do I then do this?
`tx = [x + user_x for x, user_x in product(main_tx, add_tx)]`
`ty = [y + user_y for y, user_y in product(main_ty, add_ty)]`
`list(product(tx, ty)) # get all combination`

Comment: Yes, you can do it also to create `ty` list using `main_ty` and `add_ty` in the same way as you mentioned. And to be more precise, those are not exactly combinations, but a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of elements. You have also a [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function which takes a single iterable, and a size (`int`) and returns all possible elements combinations of the specified size from the iterable.

Comment: Bah, when you said `product` I was expecting this to end with `tx = list(map(sum, product(main_tx, add_tx)))`...

Comment: Also,  you can accept the answer if it helped, or the best answer as you see fit.